# Close audits don't respect tag filters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, review-audits, filtering

I was just going through the close queue for questions tagged `java` when a C++ template metaprogramming question popped up. As suspected, this was an audit question.

Is noticing the discrepancy enough to pass the audit, or should the audit system be made aware of the tags the reviewer is filtering by?

Comment: It sounds like you've got yourself an audit.  You're paying attention at least, so passing it shouldn't be that big of a deal.

Comment: status-bydesign, per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204639/audits-bug-in-the-filtered-review-queue

Comment: Ah, the great Meta Schism. I suppose I'll leave this one open here, then.