# Close Votes Review - How does the Primarily Opinion Based filter work?

Tags: discussion

How does the "Primarily Opinion Based" filter in the Close Votes queue filter questions. I mean, what is the exact criteria used for filtering questions that fall under this.

Is it based on close votes that had been casted by other users earlier (or) based on some content evaluation (like questions with "Best Way to do ..." in the question title/content etc)?

Reason for the question is because I recently came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5611887?filter-closereason=opinionbased) in the Close votes review queue when I had filter applied to fetch only "Primarily Opinion Based" questions. The question has eventually been put on hold as "too broad". In fact when I had voted to close as broad, two of the previous votes were for the same reason while two others were "unclear what you're asking". So I would like to know how did this question come to appear when filtering for opinion based questions? Is this a **bug** or is it **by-design**?

I did also [check this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255349/close-audits-dont-respect-tag-filters) asked earlier on meta but that seems to be referring to a slightly different item (about audit questions not respecting filters).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: A thought: maybe it was *flagged* as opinion based?

Comment: You mean by a user who had less than 3000 rep so they used the flag instead of actually close voting? Sounds quite possible now that you point that out :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I would really appreciate a comment explaining the reason for the down-vote. Was it because Louis' comment is the definitive answer to this question? If yes, please add as answer so that I can accept and close the thread.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not submitting my comment as an answer because to put it as an answer I'd want to be able to verify that there was indeed an "opinion-based" flag on the question. But I don't believe I can perform this check myself. Regarding the downvote, I can't tell what happened in the mind of the downvoter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as [Louis pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269652/close-votes-review-how-does-the-primarily-opinion-based-filter-work#comment84021_269652) flagging a post pushes it to the appropriate review queue. When we click on the *Flag* button, this shows up:

[image]

Here's an [answer from a SO moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159945/185667):

> Any time a user without the vote-to-close privilege flags the question for a canned vote-to-close reason, it is automatically added to the close votes review queue as a way of reviewing the flag.

This is also confirmed when we open a post to close review and we see no actual votes on the question.

Comment: Though the queue is quite overrun on [SO], so a single flag/vote won't move things very much...

Comment: Thanks for catching the bug, @CodyGray :)